# parsing json into dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following json which I am trying to parse into a dictionary so that I get just the queries in the "Queries" that is query 1 and query 2

```
  [ 
      { "A":  "xyz", 
        "B": "this is xyz",
        "Queries":    [
                       "Query 1",
                       "Query 2" 
                      ] 
      }
    ]
```

I am using:

```
import json 
js=open('C://localpath//files.json') 
data=json.load(js) //assuming that json.load() will make data as dictionary correct me if i am wrong
```

`data.get("Queries")` ives the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

How do I get data to be a dictionary and not a list and use "Queries" to just get the queries out of json, I don't want to convert it to a list. Is there a way to directly treat it as a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
js = open('C:/temp/json.txt').read()
data = json.loads(js)
data[0]['A']
u'xyz'
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a list of dictionaries. You would need to index the dictionary out of the list

```
data[0].get('Queries')
```

Or if there are multiple dictionaries, you could use a list comprehension to get the queries from each dictionary

```
[d.get('Queries') for d in data]
```